# Does a separate /home partition have any effect on accessing speed?

Tags: boot, 18.04

I just want to know if having a separate /home partition have any effect on accessing speed of /home partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where your /home partition is located. If it's on the same drive or host, probably not. Let's say it resides on a network share, then perfomance might be an issue, depending on the network, etc.